# COleDateTime and comparing just date part

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, coledatetime

I have two `COleDateTime` variables mapped to two controls on a dialog. The controls are set as **short date**. But, the dates selected by the user **still include** timestamps internally by MFC. So, when I test the variables for equality they fail.

Given 2 `COleDateTime` objects, how can we do comparison and *ignore* the **time component**? For example, I want to do this test:

```
(datMeeting >= m_sSetup.datStart && datWeek <= m_sSetup.datEnd)
```

But the **Start** / **End** (mapped to dialog) have *time components* even though I don't need them. I just want to compare dates.

---

At the moment I am doing it this way:

```
(datMeeting.GetDay() >= m_sSetup.datStart.GetDay() &&
datMeeting.GetMonth() >= m_sSetup.datStart.GetMonth() &&
datMeeting.GetYear() >= m_sSetup.datStart.GetYear())
&&
(datMeeting.GetDay() <= m_sSetup.datEnd.GetDay() &&
    datMeeting.GetMonth() <= m_sSetup.datEnd.GetMonth() &&
    datMeeting.GetYear() <= m_sSetup.datEnd.GetYear())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`COleDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class) internally stores a [`DATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/date-type) value, accessible through its [`m_dt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class#m_dt) public member.

A `DATE` data type is a double-precision floating point value, where the whole numbers represent the date and the fractional part the time of day. Stripping the fractional part thus leaves a value representing the date only. Casting a floating point value to an integer value does exactly that:

```cpp
auto const meeting_date = static_cast<int>(datMeeting.m_dt);
auto const start_date = static_cast<int>(m_sSetup.datStart.m_dt);
auto const end_date = static_cast<int>(m_sSetup.datEnd.m_dt);

if (meeting_date >= start_date && meeting_date <= end_date) {
    // ...
}
```

Of course there's nothing wrong writing a free function, e.g.,

```cpp
[[nodiscard]]
bool is_date_in_range(COleDateTime date,
                      COleDateTime start,
                      COleDateTime end) noexcept
{
    auto const d = static_cast<int>(date.m_dt);
    auto const s = static_cast<int>(start.m_dt);
    auto const e = static_cast<int>(end.m_dt);

    return d >= s && d <= e;
}
```

that hides the intricacies and conveys a clear message about intent.

---

Note that the comparison expression as you have it now has a latent bug. It will start manifesting early next year. If `datMeeting`'s year is strictly greater than `datStart`'s year, its month and day must not be used in the comparison. If they are, some dates are wrongfully rejected.

The proposed solution above is immune to this defect as it operates on integer values which have a strict total ordering.

Comment: Thanks for identifying a bug in my logic! I have tried this approach you suggested and it is working fine. Awesome.  You proposed a free function ... but is there a possibility of a free form function that takes the two values and applies the operator? LIke a one function fits all for any operator comparison between 2 dates?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I updated the answer to fill in some gaps. Did this address your feedback, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Thanks, it was your free form function that made me wonder of possibility of a `Compare(d1, d2, operator)`. Eg: `if(Compare(a <= b) || Compare(b >= a) || Compare(a == b))`.  Maybe not possible. Eitherway, you have addressed my issue.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You could write a `Compare` function template that takes a comparison function object, but you can't use the syntax you had in mind (e.g., `Compare(a <= b)`. You'd still have to write `Compare(a, b, std::less_equal)`, for example. And that doesn't get you far, since `COleDateTime` already implements [relational operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class#coledatetime_relational_operators), and you don't get a second chance to implement them. That's a dead end. You'd have to invent a new type to get operator overload ergonomics.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining! 